# UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['MS Mincho'] not found. Using JupyterNotebook

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

Hi i have this JupyterNotebook project and im new to it. My problem is my font Ms Mincho does not work. I really dont know on how to solve this problem and im stuck on it. Iv'e check the path file but no good. Here is the error code below

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py:1320: UserWarning: findfont: Font family ['MS Mincho'] not found. Falling back to DejaVu Sans
  (prop.get_family(), self.defaultFamily[fontext]))
```

Can someone help me figured this thing out? My anaconda --version is version 1.6.9 and my python is 3.6.4. Iv'e checked my fonts in my windows then there is a Ms Mincho font installed on it. Ive seen some reference the same error as mine but i didn't find any solution. Ive also check the folder .matplotlib folder cache also. Seems no luck. Any help is muchly appreciated.

Comment: Try debugging the issue yourself: Open `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py`, go to line 1320 and look at the code that produces the warning. Add `print()` lines that output the values of the variables that are involved in producing the warning, figure out what condition triggers it. Continue doing that until you get to the root cause of why the code thinks the font is not there.

Comment: Ive seen the file. The problem is the other desktop computer works well. but in my desktop it has an error